# Can I call a UDF at Frontend

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF in sql server. I want to call this function at frontend (C# Code). Is it possible to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just grab a `SqlConnection` object and:

```
var com = yourConnection.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = "select dbo.MyUdf();";
com.ExecuteScalar();
```

If it's a table-valued UDF, use `ExecuteReader()` or something similiar.